# REtrieve field info from web map services in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes, map-service

I am trying to work out what fields are associated with a map service in ArcMap.  The service is very slow in drawing and I wondered if it was possible to retrieve attributes associated with a layer another way?

Comment: If the slowness of speed is due to the drawing speed, could you pause the drawing and open the attribute table for the layer instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the url for the map service, you can open the rest endpoint for the service in a web browser and view the layers in the map service.

http://*servername*/arcgis/rest/services/*servicename*/MapServer

Clicking on each layer name will take you to a page that shows the attributes for that layer.